# how can I put the workload back on node where it belongs after draining it?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

After draining node for maintenance pods are deleted, daemon sets ignored and and other workload is moved on other node. BUT after UNCORDONing the node workload doesn't come back.

Is there any way to configure so after draining workload goes back to where is belongs?

Answer (score 2):

It will Mark the node as schedulable but does not mean that the pod deployed on this node will for sure schedule on this node.

You can roll out the deployment to rebalance across the nodes.

```
 kubectl  rollout restart deploy -n my-namespace
```

I will suggest node affinity in your case,  each node can host a single pod. this will help to get proper pod distribution across node.

```yaml
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            labelSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helm-chart.name" . }}
                app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

[affinity and anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity)

> Is there any way to configure so that after draining workload goes back to where is belongs?

you will need to set node selector and pod tolerance for the deployment to move to specific nodes, but if there is a single node with that specific tag and you mark it as `cordon`, your pod will be stuck and it will not able to find the node.

> nodeSelector is the simplest recommended form of node selection constraint. You can add the nodeSelector field to your Pod specification and specify the node labels you want the target node to have. Kubernetes only schedules the Pod onto nodes that have each of the labels you specify.

[assign pod to node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)

```yaml
      tolerations:
        - effect: NoSchedule
          key: node_key
          operator: Equal
          value: node_key_value
```

this toleration will allow the pod to host on that particular set of nodes where tolerance matches with the selector.